# Nodemailer taking too much time to send an e-mail

Tags: node.js, socket.io, nodemailer

I'm building a notification server, that sends emails.

I'm using the node mailer library, but when I try to send an e-mail, it takes almost 5 minutes to receive the content in my inbox

I already searched why this happens and the only answer I found was to response content to tell the browser that the request has finished. Probably something like that: res.send(xxx).

But I'm using sockets to send e-mails automatically, what do I need to improve my server? My code:

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: '...',
    pass: '...'
  }
});

...

io.on('connection', function(socket){
socket.on('notify', function(object) {
var mailOptions = {
            from: '...',
            to: object.message.sendTo,
            subject: object.message.subject,
            html: object.template
        };

        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
            if (error) {
              socket.emit("error", {data : "Error!"})
            } else {
              socket.emit("sent", {data : "Email successfully sent!"})
            }
          }); 
});
});
```

What do I need to change on my code?

Comment: Does it take 5 minutes to send the email or for you to receive it in your inbox? And are you sending it to your gmail inbox?

Comment: It takes 5 minutes for me to receive in my inbox

Comment: You have considered that the delay is actually with your own mailbox provider?

Answer (score 0):

Check the headers of the emails when you receive them to figure out where the email is getting "stuck". It might be in the original server, but it might be farther along (e.g., a spam filter or a forwarder or just a server somewhere in the middle). If it is anywhere except the first hop then there may be nothing you can do in your code to actually speed things up.